# SwiftUI How to change the NavigationBarTitle and add a button from a child form

Tags: swiftui, swift5, xcode11, navigationview

I have a mainview which has 2 tabs. I placed the navigationView at the master page so I can access to its functionality in the child views. However, the title is never successfully assigned to the master view.

The second objective is adding a button on the navigation button from the child view. However, the form doesn't render it.

Here is the code. Could you please help me with changing the title from the child view and adding a button to NavigationView from the child view?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            MainView()
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("App Title"), displayMode: .inline)
        }

    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView(){

                DashboardView() 
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Dashboard"), displayMode: .inline)
                .tabItem{
                    //Image(systemName: "list.dash")
                    Image(systemName: "chart.pie")
                    Text("Dashboard")
            }.tag(0)


                AssignmentView() 
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Assignments"), displayMode: .inline)

                .tabItem{
                    Image(systemName: "briefcase")
                    Text("Assignments")
            }.tag(1)


        }

    }
}

struct DashboardView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Dashboard View")
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Dashboard View Title"), displayMode: .inline)

    }
}

struct AssignmentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Assignment View")
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Assignments View Title"), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                print("Dashboard button click")
            }) {
                Text("Submit")
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For proper navigation features work there should be only one `NavigationView` in view stack. I assume you just need to remove first `NavigationView`, because your `MainView` is `TabView` container

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MainView()
    }
}
```

At least for me, such variant gives native look&feel.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake not to remove it, In my testing code i removed it ( I also updated the above code to remove the extra NavViews). but still having problem with title update and adding a button.

Comment: In described scenario it is better to use own `NavigationView` in each tab, as was previously + remove from `ContentView`. TabView is not intended to be inside NavigationView, I assume it is not design for such purpose, and expected to be root in own view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the NavView from the MainView and added NavViews to the subviews with the help of new struct NavigationTab.

```
struct NavigationTab<Title,   Content>: View where Title: StringProtocol,  Content: View {
    var title: Title
    var content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            content()
                .navigationBarTitle(Text(title), displayMode: .inline)

        }
    }
}
```

The tab items now look like

```
NavigationTab(title: "Dashboard" ) {
                    DashboardView()
                        .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                            self.isDrawerOpen.toggle()
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "sidebar.left")
                        })
                }

                .tabItem{
                    Image(systemName: "chart.pie")
                    Text("Dashboard")
                }.tag(1)
```

I solved an initial problem of adding button on the NavView by replicating DrawerOpen Button in multiple tabs and assign the same "isDrawerOpen" variable.

But I still have a use case in the process where I need to add a button to the NavView.trailing for Submitting. Is there a way to add a button in a subview (for example DashboardView calls another view)?